# AJAX Get from file on the Computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using JQuery: `$.getJSON()` to load a json data file on my computer.

I get the error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

How do I get around this problem.

Comment: Are you trying to load a file from your own computer? If so, JavaScript is not allowed to access your computer's file system for security reasons.

Comment: it is from my own computer! so does this mean there is absolutely no way it can happen?

Comment: @No1_Melman: The only way for JavaScript to read a file from your computer is if you use an `<input type="file" />` *and* you select the file.  There is no other way.  Also, just FYI: AJAX only works with a web server.  You can't AJAX to/from your local computer (`file:///`)

Comment: Are you using 'file://'? If so, that isn't going to work since javascript can't just access a file on your computer.

Comment: with `file://` how much of the url do you need to put in? i.e. `c:\user....\data\data.json` or can i just do `file://data/data.json`

Comment: The only way to do anything of the sort is to have the files located in your website solution.  You can then use ajax to get them like any other local file, but if it is not in your web application your cannot get it using ajax

Comment: @QBM5 sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying? The `data.json` file resides in a sub folder of my website.

Comment: @No1_Melman: `file:///` needs the full path.  Example: `file:///C:/Users/You/Documents/file/data.json`.  That's an absolute path.  If you are using a relative path, you don't use the `file:///` protocol.  Problem is, you *cannot* use AJAX to/from `file:///` URLs.  You need a (local) web server.

Comment: what url are you using to access it, use a url like a relative url. "/yourSubfolder/yourFile.json"

Comment: That is the URL i'm using :)

Comment: I suggest you set up a WAMP server on your machine.  Without a webserver, you cannot make AJAX calls.

Comment: what server environment are you usings?  iis, wamp ...

Comment: @QBM5: It looks like he *isn't*.  He's just opening the HTML files in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way at the moment to get around this without using a web server.

Due to a security protocol.